# Fitting Exponential Distribution to Task Duration Counts

Tags: r, distribution, exponential, data-fitting

In my dataset, I have ants that switch between one state (in this case a resting state) and all other states over a period of time. I am attempting to fit an exponential distribution to the number of times an ant spends in a resting state for some duration of time (for instance, the ant may rest for 5 seconds 10 times, or it could rest for 6 seconds 5 times, etc.). While subjectively this distribution of durations seems to be exponential, I can't fit a single parameter exponential distribution (where the one parameter is rate) to the data. Is this possible to do with my dataset, or do I need to use a two parameter exponential distribution?

I am attempting to fit the data to the following equation (where lambda is rate):

lambda * exp(-lambda * x).

This, however, doesn't seem to be mathematically possible to fit to either the counts of my data or the probability density of my data. In R I attempt to fit the data with the following code:

```
 fit = nls(newdata$x.counts ~ (b*exp(b*newdata$x.mids)), start = 
 list(x.counts = 1, x.mids = 1, b = 1))
```

When I do this, though, I get the following message:

```
 Error in parse(text= x, keep.source = FALSE): 
 <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
 1: ~
    ^
```

I believe I am getting this because its mathematically impossible to fit this particular equation to my data. Am I correct in this, or is there a way to transform the data or alter the equation so I can make it fit? I can also make it fit with the equation lambda * exp(mu * x) where mu is another free parameter, but my goal is to make this equation as simple as possible, so I would prefer to use the one parameter version.

Here is the data, as I can't seem to find a way to attach it as a csv: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1euqdgHfHoDmQKXHrtOLcn5x5o81zY1sr9Kq6NCbisYE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You could say that your $255$ observations seem to have a total time of about $34530$, so a reasonable estimate of the rate might be about $0.0074$

Comment: It seems from your code that you are not trying to fit an exponential distribution but trying to find a nonlinear least squares fit of your two variables.  If x and y are your two columns then this fit of the 3 parameter log-logistic seems to fit well from the plot: `library(drc); fm <- drm(y ~ x, data = ants, fct = LL.3()); plot(fm)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a typo in your formula, you forgot the - sign in

```
(b*exp(b*newdata$x.mids))
```

But this is not what is throwing the error. The `start` parameter should be a list that initializes **only** the parameter value, not `x.counts` nor `x.mids`.

So the correct version would be:

```
fit = nls(newdata$x.counts ~ b*exp(-b*newdata$x.mids), start = list(b = 1))
```